# Designing an Abacus Application in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm looking to design an abacus application but unsure what to use to do what I want to do. The point is to make a simple abacus crossplatform app with PCL, so I want to create a mainpage that has three subpages, accessible by swiping right or left.

I've managed to do this by using the carousal subpage, however I'm unsure what I should use to do the vertical bars with numbers in.

My first thought was to make a stacklayout with the bar proportations and ten boxviews for each number. But how do I put a number inside each one?

Second, what could I use to make the draggable rulers and make them "click" onto the closest line of the number where you drop the rulers?

Sorry for these questions, tried googling different views and couldn't find the right view to use, textview maybe instead?

This is the application I would like to assemble https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EFSRUf_WDxo

This is what I've done so far, not much.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CarouselPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BabakusXamarin"
             x:Class="BabakusXamarin.MainPage">
    <CarouselPage.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPage>
                <ContentPage.Padding>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                        <On Platform="iOS, Android" Value="0,40,0,0" />
                    </OnPlatform>
                </ContentPage.Padding>
                <StackLayout HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="50" BackgroundColor="Aquamarine" >
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                    <StackLayout>
                        <BoxView Color="{Binding Color}"  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"  />
                        <BoxView Color="{Binding Color}"  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"  />
                        <BoxView Color="{Binding Color}"  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"  />
                        <BoxView Color="{Binding Color}"  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"  />
                        <BoxView Color="{Binding Color}"  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"  />
                        <BoxView Color="{Binding Color}"  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"  />
                        <BoxView Color="{Binding Color}"  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"  />
                        <BoxView Color="{Binding Color}"  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"  />
                        <BoxView Color="{Binding Color}"  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"  />
                        <BoxView Color="{Binding Color}"  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"  />


                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ContentPage>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselPage.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselPage>
```